# Making some detail explanations in python string

Tags: python, regex, comments

With Java, I can split the string and give some detailed explanations

```
String x = "a" + // First
           "b" + // Second
       "c";  // Third

// x = "abc"
```

How can I make the equivalence in python?

I could split the string, but I can't make a comment on this like I do with Java.

```
x = "a" \
"b" \
"c"
```

I need this feature for explaining regular expression usage.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("rename_method\\(" + // ignore 'rename_method('
                        "\"([^\"]*)\"," +    // find '"....",'
```

Comment: To comment regular expressions, consider the `re.VERBOSE` flag: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This

```
x = ( "a" #foo
      "b" #bar
    )
```

will work.

The magic is done here by the parenthesis -- python automatically continues lines inside of any unterminated brakets (`([{`).  Note that python also automatically concatenates strings when they're placed next to each other (We don't even need the `+` operator!)-- really cool.

Comment: @JoelCornett -- When I first found out that `+` was unnecessary, I thought that was SO cool (No pun intented :).  I think that particular feature exists to make multi-line strings easier to build.  The concatenation is done during parsing/compiling to bytecode too, so it's more efficient.  You can argue that's what triple quoting is for too, but it is a little funky in that it really messes up your indentation sometimes.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it specifically for regular expressions, you can do it pretty easily with the `re.VERBOSE` flag. From the Python [docs](http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html) (scroll down a bit to see the documentation for the `VERBOSE` flag):

```
charref = re.compile(r"""
 &[#]                # Start of a numeric entity reference
 (
     0[0-7]+         # Octal form
   | [0-9]+          # Decimal form
   | x[0-9a-fA-F]+   # Hexadecimal form
 )
 ;                   # Trailing semicolon
""", re.VERBOSE)
```

Comment: Important bit from the documentation for `re.VERBOSE`: "When this flag has been specified, whitespace within the RE string is ignored, except when the whitespace is in a character class or preceded by an unescaped backslash."  I once had the literal "PO BOX" in my verbose regex and couldn't figure out why it wasn't matching what I wanted.